# sshfs through multiple hosts?

Tags: ssh, mount, ssh-tunneling, sshfs

I am using `ssh` favorites in order to have a comfortable way to tunnel myself onto workstations at my university from my laptop at home.

My config looks like this:

```
host sample_workstation
    hostname sample_workstation
    port 22
    user johndoe
    ProxyCommand ssh local_server -W %h:%p

host local_server
    hostname local_server
    port 22
    user johndoe
    ProxyCommand ssh gateway_server -W %h:%p

host gateway_server
    hostname gateway_server.my.university.tld
    port 22
    user johndoe
```

Basically I am ssh'ing to `gateway_server`, which is accessible through the internet and from there to a local intranet server `local_server`, which gives me another tunnel where `sample_workstation` is reachable.

It works perfectly with ssh and is easy to use, since I just need to:

```
ssh sample_workstation
```

...and the config does the magic. However, I also would like to access files. `rsync` is one solution, but too complicated for every day use (in my opinion).

Therefore I would like to use `sshfs` to mount my workstations working directory.

How can I tunnel through `gateway_server` and `local_server` to `sample_workstation` via `sshfs`?

Comment: `sshfs` uses your ssh config by default. Have you tried simply mounting a directory on the sample workstation with sshfs? (try `sshfs sample_workstation:/home/johndoe/ ~/sample_workstation` after creating `~/sample_workstation` on the local machine)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I only found `ssh` config examples for tunneling while searching for `sshfs` - now I know why (*sighs*). I thought I need some different config specifically for `sshfs`. My fault & thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

SSHFS is using the SFTP subsystem of SSH and therefore it is using the same configuration files you have already set up. There is no need for any other configuration. Just mount the `sshfs` mount point on the remote host:

```
sshfs sample_workstation:dir /mnt/mountpoint
```